# "UnicodeEncodeError" only occurring an editor console output, such as ATOM

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, decode, atom-editor, encode

I am having a problem with printing non-ASCII characters in ATOM console. For example:

```
print("é")

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But doing the exact same thing in ***python terminal*** works perfectly fine?!?!

```
> print("é")

> é
```

What gets me more confusing is that both, python terminal and atom, have the encoding of utf-8.

```
import sys

print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
```

which outputs

```
utf-8
```

Can someone give a comprehensive explanation on why this is happening, and how to fix the error on atom.

Comment: I guess it would be useful to know which console you're using, since Atom doesn't have one by default

Comment: Yes, I am using atom-python-run package to run Python on Atom. Honestly, I am not sure if that's the right answer to your question, but hope it clarifies things. Thanks.

Comment: What about `sys.stdout.encoding`?